# The adjoint of left exterior multiplication by $\xi^\flat$ for Hodge star operator

Tags: tensor-products, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, hodge-theory

As we know, for $V$ a vector space with a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form $g$ on $V$, an orientation $\mathcal{O}$ on $V$, $e_{1},\dots,e_{n}\in V$ a $g$-orthonormal basis, and $e^1,\dots,e^n$ the associated dual basis on $V^*$, the Hodge star operator $\ast:\Lambda V^*\rightarrow\Lambda V^*$ can be defined as

$\ast(e^{1}\wedge\dots\wedge e^{n})=\pm 1$ ($+$ if $[\{e_{i}\}]=\mathcal{O}$ and $-$ if $[\{e_{i}\}]=-\mathcal{O}$)

$\ast(1)=\pm e^{1}\wedge\dots\wedge e^{n}$ (again $+$ if $[\{e_{i}\}]=\mathcal{O}$ and $-$ if $[\{e_{i}\}]=-\mathcal{O}$)

$*(e^{1}\wedge\dots\wedge e^{k})=\pm e^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge e^{n}$

From this it can be proven that $\ast\ast=(-1)^{n(n-k)}\operatorname{id}_{\Lambda V^*}$ and $\langle T,S\rangle=\ast(T\wedge\ast S)=\ast(S\wedge \ast T)$ (where $T=\eta_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge \eta_{k}$, $S=\omega_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge \omega_{k}$ and $\langle T,S\rangle=\det(\langle\omega_i,\eta_{j}\rangle)$).

For any $\xi\in V$ denote $\gamma:\Lambda^{k+1} V^*\rightarrow \Lambda^{k} V^*$ the adjoint of left exterior multiplication by $\xi^\flat=g(-,\xi)$,
$$\langle\gamma(T),S\rangle=\langle T,\xi^\flat\wedge S\rangle,$$
for all $T\in\Lambda^{k+1} V^*$ and $S\in\Lambda^{k} V^*$.

I need to prove that $\gamma(T)=(-1)^{n-k}\ast(\xi^\flat\wedge\ast T)$ but I'm a little confused, how one would prove that $\gamma$ has this expression from this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that there exists unique $\gamma:\Lambda^{k+1}V^*\rightarrow \Lambda^k V^*$ such that
$$ \langle \gamma(T),S \rangle = \langle T,\xi\wedge S \rangle .$$
This is due to the non-degeneracy of inner product $ \langle -,- \rangle .$ In fact, assume that there are two such $\gamma_1,\gamma_2.$ Fix an arbitrary $T\in\Lambda^{k+1}V^*.$ Now you get that for every $S\in\Lambda^{k}V^*$
$$ \langle \gamma_1(T),S \rangle = \langle T,\xi\wedge S \rangle = \langle \gamma_2(T),S \rangle .$$
And from non-degeneracy of $ \langle -,- \rangle $ you have that $\gamma_1(T)=\gamma_2(T).$ But $T$ was arbitrary, hence $\gamma_1=\gamma_2.$ Since there is unique $\gamma: \Lambda^ {k+1}V^*\rightarrow  \Lambda^ k V^*$ such that
$$ \langle \gamma(T),S \rangle = \langle T,\xi\wedge S \rangle ,$$
all you need to do is to check whether $\gamma(T)=(-1)^{n-k}\ast(\xi\wedge\ast T)$ has that property. This should be straightforward.
$$ \langle \gamma(T),S \rangle =*(S\wedge *\gamma(T))=*(S\wedge (-1)^{n-k}\ast\ast(\xi\wedge\ast T))=\\=(-1)^{n-k}(-1)^{nk}\ast(S\wedge\xi\wedge\ast T)=(-1)^{n-k}(-1)^{nk}(-1)^{k}\ast(\xi\wedge S\wedge \ast T)=\\=(-1)^{n-k}(-1)^{(n+1)k}\ast((\xi\wedge S)\wedge\ast T)=(-1)^{n(k+1)} \langle T,\xi\wedge S \rangle .$$
Unfortunately I am left with factor $(-1)^{n(k+1)}.$

---

EDIT

I've found that you have little flaws in your previous calculation. In fact from Warner's book "Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups," p. 80, we know that

[image]

Additionally, in p. 80 too, there is different formula for $\gamma$

[image]

Now the calculations go flawless.

$$ \langle \gamma(T),S \rangle =*(S\wedge *\gamma(T))=*(S\wedge (-1)^{nk}\ast\ast(\xi\wedge\ast T))=\\=(-1)^{nk}(-1)^{k(n-k)}\ast(S\wedge\xi\wedge\ast T)=(-1)^{nk}(-1)^{k(n-k)}(-1)^{k}\ast(\xi\wedge S\wedge \ast T)=\\=(-1)^{2nk-k^2+k}\ast((\xi\wedge S)\wedge\ast T)=(-1)^{-k(k-1)} \langle T,\xi\wedge S \rangle = \langle T,\xi\wedge S \rangle .$$

Comment: I made a mistake, the formula for your answer is the correct, thanks